# ¿Como conectar firebase con android studio?

Tags: java, android

Mi problema es el siguiente.

Tengo un proyecto en [android-studio](/questions/tagged/android-studio), pero requiero de conectarlo a la base de datos firebase, pero no he encontrao la manera de poderme conectar satisfactoriamente ya que eh intentado agregandando el paquete al firebase pero no logra conectarce.

No soy muy experto en estas cosas por la cual requiero de sus conocimientos, el motivo por el cual necesito conectar ese proyecto con la base de datos es para modificar el numero del pais en donde me encuentro y borrar algunos datos de prueba. si necesitan algo ya sea imagenes o iformacion extra favor de ponerlos en los comentarios que estare pendiente.

psdt: ya intente conectarlo usuando android studio pero no me deja ya que previamente ya  me habia logueao con otra aplicacion

Comment: Hola, ¿leíste [la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0&%3Bhl=es&hl=es)? ¿Qué pasos has dado de lo explicado allí? ¿Qué configuración tienes al respecto (gradle)? ¿Qué código tienes para conectarte a Firebase? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Hola!, puedes describir en que parte del proceso de conexion que te brinda Firebase te quedas colgado?

Comment: he intentado conectarlo por medio del paquete agregandolo directamente en el firebase, pero me pide el SHA1 y como es un proyecto que me enviaron no me aparece ese SHA1 en ese proyeto

Comment: con respecto al gradle no se mucho y que sy nuevo}

Comment: chicos todos lo que quieran ver el problema de cerca pueden entar y descargar el proyecto aqui les dejo el vinculo https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y8kdEpx2864NWO2N3wTqVgEUDqlqaTDm?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

**Paso 1 descargar "google-services.json"**

[image: Paso 1 descargar "google-services.json"]

Posteriormente mover el archivo google-services.json descargado
al directorio raíz de tu módulo (nivel de app)

**Paso 2 agragar dependencias**

[image: Paso 2 agragar dependencias]

Archivo de Gradle de nivel de raíz (nivel de proyecto) (/build.gradle):
La nueva forma de agregar `id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.14' apply false`

**Paso 3 pluggin y dependencias**

[image: Paso 3 pluggin y dependencias]

**Archivo de Gradle del módulo (nivel de app) (//build.gradle):**

Se agraga la linea `id 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se agrega las dos lineas `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2') implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'`